# PHP and Mysql dynamic input fields by append - how to construct the query for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dynamic, field

I am a total noob with php and mysql so I hope you guys can help me. I have a form that has a button where a user can add a set of input fields dynamically. I am using append to generate the fields. I was reading a tutorial about it so i understood that part. Here is the site where I based my append script on [,link here.](http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/58/adding-unlimited-form-fields-with-jquery-mysql/) My problem is how do I construct the foreach loop for the sql query if I have a set of fields and not just one input field like that website is showing as an example? Here is what my append looks like (I am just showing 4 fields but in total there is 16 fields per set of the append.) I want to upload the post data to a sql db. I've been searching the site but I was only seeing samples of foreach loop for a single input field not like the set that I have.

Thanks very much and I hope someone can give me an idea on how to proceed on this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    $(function(){
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
    count += 1;
    $('#row-fluid').append(

        '<div class="span12" style="border-bottom:1px lightgray solid; padding:10px 0px;">'
            +'<div class="row-fluid"> '                         

                +'<div class="span1">'
                +'<label>&nbsp;</label>'
                +'<label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="process_where' + count + '" name="process_where[]' + '" value="Online" onClick="checkProcessType(this.value)" >Online</label>'   
                +'<label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="process_where' + count + '" name="process_where[]' + '" value="In-store" onClick="checkProcessType(this.value)" >In-store</label>'                       +'</div>'

                +'<div class="span1">'
                +'<label>&nbsp;</label>'
                +'<label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="status' + count + '" name="status[]' + '" value="Actual" onClick="checkStatus(this.value)" >Actual</label>   '
                +'<label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="status' + count + '" name="status[]' + '" value="Ghost" onClick="checkStatus(this.value)" >Ghost</label>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div class="span1">'
                +'<label>Type</label>'
                +'<select id="upg' + count + '" name="upg[]' + '" onChange="checkExp(this.value)" class="input-small" >'
                +' <option value="" selected="&nbsp;" >&nbsp;</option>'
                +'<option value="Exp" >Exp</option>'
                +'<option value="Post" >Post</option>'
                +'<option value="Upgrade" >Upg</option>'
                +'<option value="Retail" >Retail</option>'
                +'</select>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div id="upg' + count + '" class="span2">'
                +'<label>Full Date</label>'
                +'<input name="upg_date[]' + '" id="upg_date' + count + '" type="text" id="upg_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" class="input-small" />'
                +'<img id="jscalendar' + count + '" type="image" src="img/calendar.png" style="border-width:0px; width:16px; height:16px; background-color:#FFF; margin-bottom:-7px;" onclick="createPopCalendar3()">'
                +'</div>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**And Change your php submission page like this:**

```
if(is_array($_POST[counter]))
{
$count=count($_POST[counter]);

for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
{


$process_where=$_POST["process_where".$i.""];
$status=$_POST["status".$i.""];
$upg=$_POST["upg".$i.""];
$upg_date=$_POST["upg_date".i.""];

if($process_where !="")
{
//Query Run Here
  $query="insert into tablename (process_where,status,upg,upg_date) values ('".$process_where."','".$status."','".$upg."','".$upg_date."')";
 mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}




}

}
```

Comment: Hi @VikasU For some reason I can only echo $count if I remove the whole for ($i) loop and the value is correct that the $count is counting the number of times I appended the input set.

Comment: I have edited the code now check the value of $count and loop

Comment: Yey it works!! Thanks very much @VikasU. So it was just missing the "i" in the for loop condition for the increment?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.On form submission check this code:

```
if(is_array($_POST[process_where]))
{


foreach($_POST[process_where] as $key=>$val)
{

$process_where=$_POST[process_where][$key];
$status=$_POST[status][$key];
$upg=$_POST[upg][$key];
$upg_date=$_POST[upg_date][$key];

//Query Run Here
  $query="insert into tablename (process_where,status,upg,upg_date) values ('".$process_where."','".$status."','".$upg."','".$upg_date."')";
 mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());




}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas. It seems simple enough and I actually understood what you have posted. I'll test it out as soon as I get home.

Comment: Thanks Vikas it works well my only issue now is that for those first two radio boxes "process_where" and "status" when I append another set whatever radio button i select on the first set it won't let me select any of the 2nd set or it will check the button on the 2nd set but leave the radio buttons on the first set unchecked. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Change your javascript as:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    $(function(){
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
    count += 1;
    $('#row-fluid').append(

        '<div class="span12" style="border-bottom:1px lightgray solid; padding:10px 0px;">'
            +'<div class="row-fluid"> '                         

                +'<div class="span1">'
                +'<label>&nbsp;</label>'
                +'<label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="process_where' + count + '" name="process_where' + count +'" value="Online" onClick="checkProcessType(this.value)" >Online</label>'   
                +'<label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="process_where' + count + '" name="process_where' + count +'" value="In-store" onClick="checkProcessType(this.value)" >In-store</label>'                       +'</div>'

                +'<div class="span1">'
                +'<label>&nbsp;</label>'
                +'<label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="status' + count + '" name="status' + count +'" value="Actual" onClick="checkStatus(this.value)" >Actual</label>   '
                +'<label class="radio"><input type="radio" id="status' + count + '" name="status' + count +'" value="Ghost" onClick="checkStatus(this.value)" >Ghost</label>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div class="span1">'
                +'<label>Type</label>'
                +'<select id="upg' + count + '" name="upg' + count +'" onChange="checkExp(this.value)" class="input-small" >'
                +' <option value="" selected="&nbsp;" >&nbsp;</option>'
                +'<option value="Exp" >Exp</option>'
                +'<option value="Post" >Post</option>'
                +'<option value="Upgrade" >Upg</option>'
                +'<option value="Retail" >Retail</option>'
                +'</select>'
                +'</div>'

                +'<div id="upg' + count + '" class="span2">'
                +'<label>Full Date</label>'
                +'<input name="upg_date' + count +'" id="upg_date' + count + '" type="text" id="upg_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" class="input-small" />'
                +'<img id="jscalendar' + count + '" type="image" src="img/calendar.png" style="border-width:0px; width:16px; height:16px; background-color:#FFF; margin-bottom:-7px;" onclick="createPopCalendar3()">'
                +'<input type="hidden" name="counter[]" value="1"></div>'
```

**And Change your php submission page like this:**

```
if(is_array($_POST[counter]))
{


foreach($_POST[counter] as $key=>$val)
{


$process_where=$_POST["process_where".$key.""];
$status=$_POST["status".$key.""];
$upg=$_POST["upg".$key.""];
$upg_date=$_POST["upg_date".$key.""];

if($process_where !="")
{
//Query Run Here
  $query="insert into tablename (process_where,status,upg,upg_date) values ('".$process_where."','".$status."','".$upg."','".$upg_date."')";
 mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}




}

}
```

Comment: Thanks again @Vikas Umrao, the new append script definitely fixed the issue with the radio buttons but when I submit the data to the db only the first append set gets submitted. I understood the logic of the changes you made but quick question what does this condition mean `if($process_where !="")`

Comment: Please check the value of check count,it is increasing or not ? i think it is not increasing.......make it increase on click on one row....

Comment: Add One field in the form say <input type='hidden' id='counter_increase' value='0'> .Place this field before </form> tag.Then replace var count = 0; from var count=document.getElementById('counter_increase').value(); document.getElementById('counter_increase').value=1*count+1*1;

Comment: Thank you for replying. The check count is increasing. I checked using firebug and the name/value of the field becomes process_where1, process_where2 and so on for every set

Comment: Hi Vikas, I didn't understand your last comment about adding one field before the </form> tag.Can you please elaborate a bit more on that? Thanks very much.

Comment: leave that........its was for check count.                          Have you replaced the latest code?

Comment: yes sir, I updated the code based on the last append script you posted. Still the issue is that it is only uploading one set.

Answer (score 0):

to simplify it, if I do this nothing prints.

```
if(is_array($_POST[counter]))
{
$count=count($_POST[counter]);
echo $count;

    for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
{   

    echo "The number is " . $i . "<br />";

}
```

}

But if I do this, $count prints just fine.

```
if(is_array($_POST[counter]))
{
$count=count($_POST[counter]);
echo $count;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please upload the edited version after submission

```
if(is_array($_POST[counter]))
{
$count=count($_POST[counter]);

for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
{


$process_where=$_POST["process_where".$i.""];
$status=$_POST["status".$i.""];
$upg=$_POST["upg".$i.""];
$upg_date=$_POST["upg_date".i.""];

if($process_where !="")
{
//Query Run Here
  $query="insert into tablename (process_where,status,upg,upg_date) values ('".$process_where."','".$status."','".$upg."','".$upg_date."')";
 mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}




}

}
```